# AndroidStudio - plugin error messages on start after update to 4.1

Tags: android-studio, plugins, data-binding

After upgrade Android Studio to 4.1 I am getting error message on each start:

[image]

However, I can't see these plugins on list - to uninstall or disable them:

[image]

How to fix it? Also, I am not sure what are these plugins for? I won't be able to use DataBinding anymore? Does anybody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have same issue then i just remove plugin from android studio

u can find them here

**C:\Users\Your pc name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins**

Comment: I'm on Linux, so folder path is `~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1` but yest deleting folders solved issue.

Comment: On macOS, `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins/`